# Virtualbox change guest windows 7 resolulation to 16:9 (1280x720)

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution

i have a vm (windows 7) on oracle virtual box. But the problem is resolution is 4:3 means 800x600, 1200x960

but for my purposes, i need 16:9 specifically 1280:720

i have searched a lot on google and tried all possible way at my end but neither didn't work

**a) some told, it must have guest addition, it has**

**b) i have use command line for vboxmanage to set customvideomode1**

**c) i have tried enable and disable 3D and 2D accelerator**

**d) i have tried allocating maximum ram and video memory**

**e) i have tried display option from preferences to set hint as 1920:1080**

how ever none of them seems to work :(

so, i am out of way and wondering if some one can help me out :)

Note: i run vm in full screen mode but it doesn't show in full screen. it shows the window size (1280x960)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 with guest addition installed match the resolution to the virtualbox window size. each time you change the windows size the resolution is changed accordingly.

This is the default behavior, if not - make sure your guest addition is really installed and running.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but sir, i know that's the normal behavior but it not works like that. and yes, i have double check even reinstall guest addition.. but still nothing :(

Comment: Sounds like a drivers issue. Is it clean win or some customized version?